# Request empty on laravel side when sending post with angular

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel

I am new to Angular, and want to make a POST with Angular, and receive it with Laravel 5.5

Here is my Angular code, it seems that variables have data:

```
onSubmit(form: NgForm): Promise<Item> {
  console.log(form.value);
  return this._http.post('http://api-test.dev/api/items', JSON.stringify(form.value))
  .toPromise()
  .then(res => res.json().data)
  .catch(this.handleError);
```

}

`console.log(form.value);` gives me: `{name: "12", price: "2"}`

Item object has only 2 fields, `name` and `price`

It hits the Laravel controller, but `$request` variable is null...

I tried the same POST with Postman, and it works great, so it must be something with Angular.

Any idea?

Comment: What does your chrome dev console say? Any errors what about XHR filter when you "send" the data is it actually sent?

Comment: Well, Laravel send me a FK Not Null Error because I try to insert a empty name, that cannot be null

Comment: I am talking about [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMmSA.png).

Comment: Yes, me too :) well, in my controller, I just do a `return json_encode($request->all());` but it returns: []
No Properties ( In chrome XHR Preview).  If I run my script without logging anything, it will give me a 500 with a SQL FK  Error

Answer (score 0):

I am not so expert. But i was faced same problem. And this way i sent my data.

```
$scope.data = {

        name: 'name',
        email: 'example@gmail.com'
    };
$http.post(uploadUrl, data)
        .success(function(response){
            //execute some code...
        });
```

It can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it including headers:

```
onSubmit(form: NgForm): Promise<Item> {
    const myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: myHeaders });


    return this._http.post('http://api-test.dev/api/items', JSON.stringify(form.value), options)
      .toPromise()
      .then(res => res.json().data)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

and now it works!